# how to loop and read from a file, a particular integers or strings using index in python?

Tags: python, file

I have currently in file one.txt:

```
99999 5286
88888 3478
```

I want to read only the numbers 99999, 88888 not the other numbers using a loop and write it to a file two.txt.

Comment: So you want the first integer from every line?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: You can't just read down the left column. You have to read everything and ignore what you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split` will split a string on whitespace, eg, `"a b   c  d"` will become `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

The docs on split: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Solution to example:

```
with open('one.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('two.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for in_string in in_file.readlines():
        out_file.write(in_string.split()[0])
        out_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for post Moses!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_specific_strings(file, *look_for):
    look_for = [str(x) for x in look_for]
    f = open(file, 'rb').readlines()
    out = []
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip().split(' ')
        print i[0]
        if i[0] in look_for:
            out.append(i[1])
    return out
print get_specific_strings('add', 99999, 88888, 66666, 55555)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `numbers = [line.split(" ")[0] for line in open('one.txt')]` to read the numbers

Writing it in the new file is as simple as:

`output_file = open('two.txt', 'w+')
    for number in numbers:
      output_file.write("%s\n" % number)`